# ubuntu terminal freezes using gcloud compute ssh

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, gcloud

After I ssh into a compute engine instance using 'gcloud compute ssh' the terminal freezes after ~2 minutes of inactivity forcing me to close the terminal and ssh back again...
any ideas what might be causing this or how to fix it? It's really disturbing when working.
Thanks,
jaime

Comment: Have you tried adding something like `ServerAliveInterval 60` to your `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` file in your local computer? This will send packets every 60 seconds in order to keep the connection.

Answer (score 0):

as Adrián commented, the ServerAliveInterval is the key. 
You can set in /etc/ssh/ssh_config or as I did in ~/.ssh/config